Traefik path with /#/
I've set up Traefik in Docker. I've encountered the following issue: I have a URL like https://example.net/#/foo, https://example.net/#/bar/foo etc. that I want to redirect to another domain on a different server, while keeping only the domain name changed, for example, to https://example2.net/#/foo. Essentially, I'm having trouble handling the "#" in the URL.
PathPrefix(/#/foo)" doesn't work
How can I solve this problem

Anything after # is not sent to the server. You'd need to handle this on the client side.

Does this answer your question? Is the anchor part of a URL being sent to a web server?

As @ceejayoz said, whatever after the hash is not sent to the server, the reason is that "#" is a special character for the URL. everything after it points to a part inside the document, thus its handled by the client. Maybe, depending on the configuration of your server you could use %23 instead of # as its the encoded version. This way it will be sent to the server, and ideally the server would convert  %23 back to #, but you'd have to try. I don't recommend using those special chars unless you have no other option.
